# cannot pull public MongoDB image from docker hub

Tags: docker

I am just starting to use docker and I wanted to pull the latest MongoDB image from docker hub.

So, from the command line I used:

```
docker pull mongo
```

this is what I found here (https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/)

Now, this comes back with:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/mongo
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
```

I also tried something like:

```
docker pull python:3.6
```

and this works.

I am on Mac OSX (High Sierra 10.13.6). I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following url seems to suggest that images tagged "unstable, 4.1, 4.1.2, latest, 4, 4.0, 4.0.1" were updated 2 hours ago. I was able to pull the image tagged latest earlier in the day but not now.

https://hub.docker.com/r/library/mongo/tags/

I can still pull 4.1.1 so it seems that it's not all the mongo images, just the ones that have been refreshed in the last couple of hours.

Comment: Ah ok! So, it is actually something wrong with the docker hub or rather the mongo library? So it is probably the latest updates that have broken something?

Comment: Best guess. Googling the error message returned very few results so it might be a rare occurrence generally.

Comment: Also noticed that these latest images are tremendously bloated...6 GB..

Answer (score 1):

Per https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1608 and https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/3835, this appears to be a common condition that they are working on resolving.

In this specific case, it's just a matter of time for it to resolve itself.